# i need some help in web browser windows forms

Tags: c#, html, winforms

im trying to click on button to sumbit my log in and im trying to get the id but when i right click on it and select inspect to look for the id= in html i cant find the id for the button... here is the html:

```
<a><button class="jssubmit btn color sf" type="button"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z"/></svg></button></div><span>
```

any one have any idea how can i click that Button?

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 ").InvokeMember("Click")    

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sumbit").InvokeMember("click")    

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("jssubmit").InvokeMember("click")

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button").InvokeMember("click")

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("jssubmit btn color sf").InvokeMember("click")
```

when i try all of those up is says get element by id(..) returned nothing...

Comment: the html code i want to get the element id is (a><button class="jssubmit btn color sf" type="button"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8-8-8z"/></svg></button></div><span )

Comment: Could you indent your code in your question, and provide a correct excerpt? Currently the `<a>` tag is not closed for instance.

Comment: The element doesn't have an id, so you'll have to find it by another property. Such as its classes, and/or is position (i.e. relative to parents or siblings), or by its contents.

Comment: This question needs a much better title.  I feel certain most questions on SO were asked because the OP needed help.

Comment: `var element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.GetAttribute("className").Contains("jssubmit")); if (element != null) element.InvokeMember("click");`

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is selenium

https://www.seleniumhq.org/

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html

check those

also not every element will have an id